# Direct sum Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a projection (an afinity that verifies $f'^{2} = f'$) and since

$u = f'(u) + (u - f'(u)) \longrightarrow$ $E  =  ker(f' - Id)\bigoplus ker(f')$,

I don't see how this follows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't fully understand your notation or problem statement, but I *think* this is just decomposing a vector space into a linear subspace and its orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 1):

Because we know that projections are idempotent (the identity you stated in the beginning), we know a key fact: the translation component of this affinity is the identity translation.

Then we know that this affinity can be expressed as a good 'ole linear mapping. Let's examine it's potential matrix representation.

If $f'$ is non-diagonalizable, then it means if you take a basis that puts $f'$ in Jordan Canonical form, then there is some vector $v_i$ in the basis such that

$$f'(v_i) = v_{i-1}+\lambda v_i$$

, and

$$f'^2(f'(v_i)) = f'(v_{i-1}+\lambda v_i)  = f'(v_{i-1})+f'(\lambda v_i)$$
$$= f'(v_{i-1})+\lambda f'(v_i) = \lambda v_{i-1} + \lambda (v_{i-1} + \lambda v_i) $$

This mapping is obviously not idempotent, so $f'$ must be diagonalizable, and we have a basis of eigenvectors, $\mathcal{B}$. For each  $ b_i \in \mathcal{B}$,

$$f'(b_i) = \lambda_ib_i \Rightarrow f'(f'(b_i)) = {\lambda_i}^2 b_i$$

So for $f'$ to be diagonalizable, we have to have each $\lambda_i = {\lambda_i}^2 $ Because $\lambda $ is an element of the underlying field, we know that this is only true in the case that $\lambda = 1 $ or $\lambda = 0 $.

Thus we have a matrix representation that is entirely ones and zeros on the diagonal, whose kernel are the vectors corresponding to $\lambda = 0 $ and whose range corresponds to $\lambda = 1 $. Taking $(f' - I) $, the kernel, or the zero eigenspace $E_o $ turns into $E_{-1} $, and $E_1 $ goes to the zero eigenspace, or the kernel $E_0 $.

*Because $ker(f'-I) = Range(f')$, we have

$$ker(f'-I) \bigoplus ker(f') = Range(f'-I) \bigoplus ker(f') = E$$

Because for any linear mapping $T$, $Range(T) \oplus Kernel(T) = V $ for any finite dimensional vector space $V$.

The most obvious metaphor for a projection is an image such as this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [unl.edu](http://emweb.unl.edu/Math/mathweb/vectors/Image510.gif))</sub>

The projection acted upon $A$ here is just using a basis called $v_x, v_y, v_z $, and projecting $A$ to the subspace $\mathbb{F}-span{v_x, v_y}$, where the eigenvector $v_z $ is sent to zero and is the kernel.

*Put this in afterwards because I realized I forgot to mention direct sums.